# Slim Syntax for Inline Div/Table Classes with Embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I have a table defined in slim:

```
 table
    tr
       td
          =_("Some Content")
       td
          =_("Some Content")
```

I would like to add some classes to certain td tags. I can do so like this:

```
 table
    tr
       td.extraclass
          =_("Some Content")
       td
          =_("Some Content")
```

This adds "extraclass" to that td:

```
 <td class="extraclass"> Some Content </td>
```

How can I add a class by embedding some rails/ruby into this? In normal rails I could do:

```
 <td class="<%=@article.attribute%>">
```

How do I do this here? I don't think I can do:

```
        td.=_(@article.attribute)
```

But I would like to add classes in some similar way here. Anybody have any advice? if I have not been clear in what I'm attempting to do, please let me know what I can add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doc for this feature is [here](http://slim-lang.com/docs.html#dynamic-content-in-attribute):

```
td class="#{@article.attribute}"
```

Comment: that's great. thanks! need to wait a few minutes to award the answer

Comment: The string interpolation is not necessary here, slim accepts `td class=@article.attribute` as well, which is less noisy.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Attributes) you can achieve this as follows:

`td class=@article.attribute`

Btw., when writing `td.class1 class=some_ruby_expr`the two classes will automatically be merged into the resulting `class` attribute.